# ctags never stops when I try to build a tag file for all python libraries

Tags: python, ctags

I used to use ctags to generate a tags file for all installed python libraries by this command:

```
C:\Windows\System32>ctags -R -f d:\home\vimfiles\python.ctags d:\Python26
```

But this morning, after I upgraded to Python 2.6.7, that command only generates the following output and never finishes its job.  The size of the tags file doesn't change anymore once it reaches about 11MB.

```
ctags: Warning: ignoring null tag in d:\Python26\Lib\copy.py
ctags: Warning: ignoring null tag in d:\Python26\Lib\pickle.py
ctags: Warning: ignoring null tag in d:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py
```

What might cause this problem?

Comment: I was about to suggest running ctags under strace, but I see you're on Windows... Still, I guess you could find a process monitor that shows file handles owned by processes, and see what file ctags has open. It's probably getting stuck on some problematic spot, and that spot should be in one of the open files.

Comment: Using Exuberant Ctags 5.5.4 against /usr/local/lib/python2.6 on my Linux box works as expected, and produces a 6.3M file. Sorry I'm not able to be more helpful, don't have a Windows computer handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Gintautas You are genius.

I found ctags was stopped by this file :

```
D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10-py2.6.egg\share\doc\ipython\manual\html\searchindex.js
```

Exclude it by set the following ctags option could resolve the problem.

```
--exclude=searchindex.js
```

I guess it's a bug of ctags.