# Vim: How to go to the declaration (of a class, method, function, variable, etc)

Tags: vim, tags

Right now I am working on a file which uses many classes, methods, functions, variables, etc. Is it possible to go to the declaration of all of them? Please, take into account that some of those declarations are in the same file but others are in other files (which may not be opened and you do not know where the declarations are but they do exist). What would happen if the declaration is one level up in the directory? and what about if it is one level down?

Is this done in a different way according to the programming language we are talking about or the procedure to find the declarations is the same regardless of the language?

I have been reading and it seems the solution is related to tags. However, I would like to know how this can be achieved (step by step), especially taking into account that we are talking, in some cases, of definitions in other files.

I know this can be done with IDEs but I would like to know how much different this can be achieved with vim.

I only have a fresh install of Vim. I have not installed any plugins yet but willing to do if it is necessary. Perhaps this can be done without and with plugins.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, in Vim this is best done with tags. Have you read the built-in documentation (`:help tags`), and what exactly are you struggling with?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Thanks for your comment. I read it and I am struggling with the fact that different files can be involved in the search of the declarations. Besides, it is not clear for me if all this is done differently depending on the programming language.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Setting up *tags* is not so difficult, though (as most things in Vim) it's not as automatic compared to IDEs.

1. First, you need the `ctags` tool. The most common in 2022 is [Universal Ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags); in 2013 it was *Exuberant Ctags*, found at [ctags.sourceforge.net](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).
2. Next, you need to create a *tags database* (a file names `tags`) for all the files in your project(s). This is usually done by running `ctags -R .` from your project root (also from within Vim via `:!ctags ...`). Exuberant Ctags support [41 languages](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html), and you can even extend it via regular expressions.
3. Finally, Vim needs to be configured to pick up the *tags database*. With `:set tags=./tags;`, it will search in the file's directory upwards to the root directory. If you have certain global include directories, you can add those.
4. With that, you can start using Vim's tag functionality like `<C-]>` and `:tag`.

You need to periodically update the *tags database*; there are plugins (like [easytags.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114); 2022 warning: unmaintained, but still working) that can do that automatically for you.

Comment: Your answer worked. Thank you very much. Do you know how to fix the issue that appears when `ctags -R .` is run? It says `ctags: Warning: ignoring null tag in file.js` . Although I have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924289/ctags-never-stops-when-i-try-to-build-a-tag-file-for-all-python-libraries), it is not clear for me, an Ubuntu user, how to fix it.

Comment: Pass the `--exclude=file.js`, or just ignore the warning.

Comment: I'll accept the answer since it was helpful.However, I would like to ask you three last questions: A) What would happen if the definition of a function (for example) is downwards?  I ask you this because you say that tags will be searched in the file's directory **upwards** to the root directory. If no declarations would be found, could you tell me if there is a workaround for this, please? B) How can I add certain global include directories to the tags database? C) Are you talking about [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path), aren't you?

Comment: A) With `ctags -R`, the database is created in the current (project root) directory, so all files will be **downwards**; from the file's perspective, this is the other way around, so don't worry.

Comment: B) Read `:help 'tags'` and `:help file-searching` (and don't be intimidated!). C) Yes, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions. You were really helpful.

Comment: The question asks for declaration. Ctrl+] will take you to the definition, but not to the declaration.

I've joined a project where the usage documentation exists as comments in the *.h files with the declarations rather than in the *.c files with the definitions.  It would be really handy to have some way to jump to the declaration as well as the definition.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I needed to to use ctags's --LANG-kinds= option to add function prototypes. vim's :tselect command then makes it easy to jump to either the prototype or the definition.

Comment: @bobpaul I tried that but still could not get prototype entries - tselect only lists definition tags (kind 'f'). How did you make it work?

Comment: Great overview to get started! Meanwhile there is [universal-ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags), the successor of exuberant ctags that supports more languages as well like Go, Rust etc..

Answer (score 9):

You can try `gd`, it goes to local declaration, for more powerful 'go to definition', you might want to try `tags` as Ingo suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [you complete me (ycm) plugin](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/youcompleteme) for this, which is

> a fast, as-you-type, fuzzy-search code completion engine for Vim

It works with a bunch of languages and is very powerful. Check [this section](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/youcompleteme#installation) for how to install it on your system.

When e.g. using it with a Java Maven project, open the desired file from the folder that contains your `pom.xml` file and the plugin scans all your files and dependencies.

I do have the following key mappings in my `~/.vimrc` for convenient use of your requested feature:

```
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<C-n>', '<Down>']
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<C-p>', '<Up>']
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = '<C-n>'
nnoremap <leader>jd :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>
nnoremap <leader>ji :YcmCompleter GoToImplementation<CR>
nnoremap <leader>jr :YcmCompleter GoToReferences<CR>
```

Assuming your `<leader>` is mapped to `,` with `let mapleader = ","` as in my case the following commands work:

- `,jd` go to definition or declaration
- `,ji` go to implementation
- `,jr` go to references
- `Ctrl+n`/`Ctrl+p` move down/up in a list that pops up for autocompletion

Comment: That's good! However, Vim has got ```gd``` for get definition, which you can use without ycm